# Elixir how to get map from ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'd like to get a data structure from ecto which allow to write iteraly something like this in my HTML :

```
<%= genders.name %>
```

So I think I should have :

```
[{name: "Male", id: 1}, {name: "Female", id: 2}]
```

Right now my controller run well

```
defmodule HexProjectWeb.LandingController do
  use HexProjectWeb, :controller

  alias HexProject.Gender

  def index(conn, _params) do
    genders = HexProject.Repo.all(Gender) |> Enum.map(&{&1.name, &1.id})

    conn
    |> assign(:genders, genders)
    |> render("index.html")
    #render conn, "index.html", genders: genders
  end
end
```

But it return me genders like this:

```
[{Male, 1}, {Female, 2}]
```

And I don't know how to show this.

So I tried

```
genders = HexProject.Repo.all(
  from g in Gender,
  select: %{name: g.name, id: g.id}
)
```

And it return me an error

> function HexProjectWeb.LandingController.init/1 is undefined (module HexProjectWeb.LandingController is not available)

edit: full error

[error rendering view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuqAO.png)

edit2: router.ex

```
defmodule HexProjectWeb.Router do
  use HexProjectWeb, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", HexProjectWeb do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    get "/landing", LandingController, :index
    resources "/genders", LandingController
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  # scope "/api", HexProjectWeb do
  #   pipe_through :api
  # end
end
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Your second attempt is correct. That error looks unrelated to this change. Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: I took a screenshot and edited my post. It is what you asked ?

Comment: In which file have you defined the `HexProjectWeb.LandingController` module? From that error it looks like you're using this module name in the router but Elixir can't find that module.

Comment: Yes I define it in my router.ex. Post edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fix those problems separately.

For your first approach, you should have:

```
genders = HexProject.Repo.all(Gender) |> Enum.map(&%{name: &1.name, id: &1.id})
```

For the second approach, where you're building the query in your controller, you should add import at the top of the file, but inside your controller definition, eg:

```
defmodule HexProjectWeb.LandingController do
  use HexProjectWeb, :controller

  import Ecto.Query # add this line

  alias HexProject.Gender
```

In your first attempt, you are actually building a tuple, it should be replaced with correct map syntax (`%{}` instead of `{}`).

Second problem you've encountered is unfortunately related to the fact you're using macro, and truly it relates to the lack of availability of `from` function in your controller.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not sure how OP can get a "module not available" error because they used a macro in the module?

Comment: Thank you, the both solutions work perfectly. Just one more question. Which solution should I choose if I have a big list of elements to show ? Is it negligible or one of solution have better performance with a big amount of data ?

Comment: @Dogbert I agree - I shared this mostly based on my personal experience and loosing countless amount of _minutes_, and usually this fairly cryptic and unassociated error message was due to lack of this specific import.

Comment: @Gotrek I'm afraid I don't have accurate answer for you straight away, usually you would need kind of benchmarking to double confirm assumptions, but if my gut feeling would be to come with crafted query (thus, the second approach), but I'm not sure this is the best approach to start with.